# List is empty outside of function even after adding the list outside

Tags: vb.net, list

I am using Visual Studio, web forms, and vb.net. Why is my list count 0 outside of PopulateNames()?

I have a list at the top of my vb.net code:

```
    Private defaultNames As List(Of ListItem) = New List(Of ListItem)()
```

I can add items to my list here:

```
'Populate cbNames with all names
Private Sub PopulateNames()
    Using sqlConn As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("databasehere").ConnectionString)
        sqlConn.Open()

        Using sqlCmd As New SqlCommand()
            sqlCmd.CommandText = "select [ID], [FirstName] from vwNames"
            sqlCmd.Connection = sqlConn

            Using sdr As SqlDataReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader()
                While sdr.Read()
                    Dim item As New ListItem()
                    item.Text = sdr("FirstName").ToString()
                    item.Value = sdr("ID").ToString()

                    'Add name from database into checkboxlist
                    cbNames.Items.Add(item)

                    'Add item from checkboxlist cbNames into list defaultNames
                    defaultNames.Add(item)

                End While
            End Using
        End Using
End Sub
```

defaultNames is count of 6 in PopulateNames() but count of 0 anywhere else. Why won't my list items save into my defaultNames list?

Comment: checkbox? What does this have to do with a checkbox?

Comment: What library does ListItem exist in?

Comment: @Mary I am storing all items from the checkboxlist (cbNames) into a list I created called defaultNames.

Comment: The code here don't highlight the error. Where are you trying to read it after running this method?

Comment: @Alejandro I am sorry for not including that. I am trying to read it literally anywhere else haha. So for example, `Protected Sub BtnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnAdd.Click PopulateNames() Dim listCount = defaultNames.Count() ` where listCount will equal 0 even though there are 6 items that were added.

Comment: If this is a web application, please add that to your tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumption: This is a Winforms application.

Don't open the connection until directly before the `.Execut...`. To save a few indents, you can combine the connection `Using` and the command `Using` with a comma at the end of the connection `Using`. You can pass the `CommandTex`t and the `Connection` directly to the constructor of the `Command`.

You don't want to fill lists and, definitely, you don't want to update the user interface (comparatively, a very slow process) while the connection is open. `Readers` require an open connection. Just fill a `DataTable` and shut down the database objects.

To fill the `CheckedListBox` just set the `DisplayMember`, `ValueMember` and `DataSource`.

```
Private Sub PopulateNames()
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using sqlConn As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("databasehere").ConnectionString),
        sqlCmd As New SqlCommand("select [ID], [FirstName] from vwNames", sqlConn)
        sqlConn.Open()
        Using sdr As SqlDataReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader()
            dt.Load(sdr)
        End Using
    End Using
    cbNames.DisplayMember = "FirstName"
    cbNames.ValueMember = "ID"
    cbNames.DataSource = dt
End Sub
```

`ListItem` is not a type available without a reference and Imports to a special library.

For a web application

```
Private Sub PopulateNames()
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using sqlConn As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("databasehere").ConnectionString),
        sqlCmd As New SqlCommand("select [ID], [FirstName] from vwNames", sqlConn)
        sqlConn.Open()
        Using sdr As SqlDataReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader()
            dt.Load(sdr)
        End Using
    End Using
    cbNames.DataSource = dt
    cbNames.DataTextField = "FirstName"
    cbNames.DataValueField = "ID"
    cbNames.DataBind()
End Sub
```

To access the DataTable you can either make a class level variable or create a Function and return the DataTable

```
Private Function GetNameData() As DataTable
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using sqlConn As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("databasehere").ConnectionString),
        sqlCmd As New SqlCommand("select [ID], [FirstName] from vwNames", sqlConn)
        sqlConn.Open()
        Using sdr As SqlDataReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader()
            dt.Load(sdr)
        End Using
    End Using
    Return dt
End Function

Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim dt = GetNameData()
    cbNames.DataSource = dt
    cbNames.DataTextField = "FirstName"
    cbNames.DataValueField = "ID"
    cbNames.DataBind()
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. In general, how can I update a list or even a variable throughout my entire application? Why doesn't defaultNames update when I add an item to it? I would need the datatable you created to be accessible and editable outside of the function PopulateNames() as well.

Comment: How can I access this data table outside of this function? IE: I place this outside of PopulateNames()... `Private dt As New DataTable` (this doesn't work though... if I try to count the rows in a different function, for example)

Answer (score 1):

You need to read up on scope.

```vb
Private defaultNames As List(Of ListItem) = New List(Of ListItem)()
```

Is scoped to an instance of a class, and is initialized with a new list whenever the containing class is instantiated.  For a form, that will most likely be whenever it is shown.

Even if you do want that private member and don’t want to expose it elsewhere, populating it the way you do is simply bad.

It should either be a parameter that gets filled, or it should be the result of a function, or the data reader should be returned and used to populate the list, or there should be a function passed in as a parameter that does something with it.

Also, although it entails more work, you probably shouldn’t be using a list item (a GUI class) whether this is a web form or winform applications.  Which is why I prefer the last 2 option’s and think the last is generally best if you are going to do something with it yourself as opposed to passing it off to something else:

```vb
Private sub init()

PopulateNames(Sub(dr as IDataReader)
                Dim item As New ListItem()
                item.Text = dr("FirstName").ToString()
                item.Value = dr("ID").ToString()

                'Add name from database into checkboxlist
                 cbNames.Items.Add(item)

                 'Add item from checkboxlist cbNames into list defaultNames
                 defaultNames.Add(item)

              End sub
End Sub

Private Sub PopulateNames(loader as Action(Of IDataReader))
    Using sqlConn As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("databasehere").ConnectionString)
        sqlConn.Open()

        Using sqlCmd As New SqlCommand()
            sqlCmd.CommandText = "select [ID], [FirstName] from vwNames"
            sqlCmd.Connection = sqlConn

            Using sdr As SqlDataReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader()
                While sdr.Read()
                   loader(sdr)
                End While
            End Using
        End Using
End Sub
```

Given this structure, if you make the PopulateNames method public, it can be used in multiple different ways.  You are no longer limited to creating a list of ListItems, as all of the actual work is done in the lambda (or if you prefer in a separate function).